# Spacetime manifold surgery: is this result still a valid etc. spacetime?

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, topology, geodesics

Given a valid classical GR spacetime manifold $M$ (i.e. 4D, Lorentzian, Hausdorff, paracompact, ?etc.), and $B\subset M$, a closed spatial subset (e.g. a closed ball at fixed $t$) to be excised,

[Aside: sorry - I try to be as precise as I can up front and this does seem to lead to unshort questions.]

**The questions are**:

a) Is the manifold $M' = M - B$ also a valid spacetime?

b) What is the argument/proof either way?

c) If $M'$ is not a valid spacetime, can it be repaired by some suitable surgery (other than putting back the excised subset)?

d) If $M$ is globally hyperbolic (GH), and $M'$ is either valid or can be repaired, is valid/repaired $M'$ also GH?

[NB: e.g. valid spacetime = Gödel; valid + GH = Minkowski]

My *belief* is that $M'$ is not a valid spacetime (or globally hyperbolic), but I can't demonstrate it*.

**The objective of the question** is to gain a better understanding of relevant technicalities, which I am *aware of* but do not comprehend; understanding the answers would be an entrée to better appreciation of theory.

Technical answers are welcome (esp. for citations and references to key theorems) even more so if they come with non-technical paraphrases that will help in understanding the technicalities.

One aspect of what I'm seeking is an insight into what you can and cannot do to a manifold in GR and why/why not. For example, in discussions of wormhole construction by surgery on Minkowksi/Schwarschild space I read the comment that after identification of surfaces (around excised open balls) "spacetime is geodesically complete" but whilst that is intuitively sensible, it is not *obviously* true *to me*.

* I believe that $M'$ is singular, having  incomplete forward and backward directed timelike (and null ?+ spacelike) geodesics, but I'm also confused about completeness vs. extensibility and ? their relations to paracompactness, etc. I also don't think $M'$ is repairable because $B$ is closed and I haven't seen any reference in my searching to being able to rejoin open sets without adding "boundaries/closure". NB I am aware of extensive literature on how hard it is to define "singular" esp. w.r.t. geodesic completeness (e.g. Hawking, Penrose, Geroch, Earman, Curiel, etc.)... but I'd rather not go *too* deep.

[**Optional subsidiary question**. A potentially more complex instance might be: take two half-infinite world tubes starting/ending on $t=0$ (i.e. half-open $[0,+\infty)$ and $[0,-\infty)$) that have no spatial overlap and excise them from Minkowksi spacetime. Can the "ends" of the cylinders around $t=0$ be joined somehow to repair the spacetime?]

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? A manifold with a closed ball removed will still be a manifold and, I suspect, still capable of hosting a Lorentzian metric on it (the resulting manifold won't be compact so there are no problems relating to having a continuous vector field on it). It may well be geodesically incomplete, but that usually isn't in the definition of a valid spacetime manifold (although it will make it fail to be globally hyperbolic).

Comment: @slereah By valid I meant that which came after "i.e.". Since I'm no expert in this I thought it best not to attempt to be definitive, though given that GH typically includes the absence of naked singularities and compactness of the causal diamond IIRC, I might have said GH in place of "valid" but I didn't want to incorrectly exclude things I was ignorant of. I said suspect $M'$ is *singular* without being definitive about geodesics and that I am unclear about incompleteness/inextensibility...

Comment: If you think that naked singularities are a problem for a spacetime, then yes, I'd say removing an open ball is not gonna be all that good.

Comment: @slereah *Closed* ball; if I removed an open ball I could identify points on the boundary, couldn't I? (Hence the emphasis on the closed ball.)

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I meant closed ball.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove a closed subset from a valid spacetime, then the result is a valid spacetime.

You can put the Lorentzian metric on the original spacetime, then simply restrict it to the part that you keep.

So it's still a 4d manifold without boundary. It's still Lorentzian and so on. You could even imagine the original manifold as some charts and transition maps with a metric on them that satisfies some compatibility conditions. Since the charts are from open sets to open sets removing a closed set doesn't change that the leftover is still open. So everything is still exactly what you require.

> d) If $M$ is globally hyperbolic (GH), and $M'$ is either valid or can be repaired, is valid/repaired $M'$ also GH?

Removing a portion can leave the result as not globally hyperbolic.

An example is Minkwoski spacetime then remove a closed ball of radius $R$ at time $t=0$. It's not globally hyperbolic.

To prove it is not globally hyperbolic, basically you can start with Minkowski spacetime $M$ and use the coordinates that have spatial zero be the center of the ball. Then consider the events $p=(R/c,\vec 0)$ and $q=(-R/c,\vec 0)$.

As subsets of your manifold $M'=M-B,$ the set $J^-(p+\hat t,M')\cap J^+(q-\hat t,M')$ is not compact because the following open sets $$M-\left( J^-(p+\frac{\hat t}{n},M)\cap J^+(q-\frac{\hat t}{n}t,M)\right)$$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ cover $J^-(p+\hat t,M')\cap J^+(q-\hat t,M')$ but the open cover fails to have a finite subcover (any finite subcover is just the largest one since the open sets get strictly bigger, and that fails to cover the whole of $J^-(p+\hat t,M')\cap J^+(q-\hat t,M')$). So $J^-(p+\hat t,M')\cap J^+(q-\hat t,M')$ is just not a compact set.

But just because you have a valid spacetime doesn't make it nice. For instance these spacetimes have curves that just stop after a finite amount of time. It's not appropriate to call them singularities since the spacetime could be extended (even though the curves in the fixed spacetime cannot).

Comment: Thank you, and, yes, that makes sense. Minkowski - (open) ball $\rightarrow$ valid (not what I thought) but not GH (and it can't be patched up...?) which was my intuition.

"Proving it is not GH is hard..." that is what I would really now like to do/see done :) Is it not GH because: (i) the curves that just end are naked singularities; (ii) because the surgery makes $J^{+}(p)\cap J^{-}(q)$ non-compact? (In which case is it because $J^{\pm}$ are no longer closed?) or (iii) because a CTC has been created (by Geroch; hasn't the topology changed?) Are (i) and (ii) the same thing here?

Comment: [...] That curves that just stop relates to the incomplete/extensible part; could you say which category do they fall into and why?

Comment: Erratum: Minkowski - CLOSED ball $\rightarrow$ valid etc.

Comment: the CLOSED ball erratum was me correcting my 1st comment (out of time to re-edit); not disputing it didn't need patching to be valid.

Comment: Thank you greatly; have to go AFK now but will be reading the edit carefully. If you are feeling generous... can this mutiliated spacetime be made GH (again the original question about joins of open sets)? [Apparently I can only +1 your answer once]

Comment: @JulianMoore Just put the ball snapshot back in and it's GH again.

Comment: Even I'd worked that one out :-) Any other way? (And, ps, what are the hats on the t's?)

Comment: @JulianMoore The hat means it is a unit length (four) vector. I do think asking for all the *different* ways to extend a spacetime depends on what extensions you consider to be equivalent, and would be a different question, that should be asked as a new question. And like all of mathematical relativity it will hinge a great deal on the exact precise definitions.

Comment: I've worked through it now and I have some questions - SE says avoid extended discussions in comments... how should I proceed? (I've illustrated the regions and would like to share the images.)

Comment: @JulianMoore If it's a new question, ask it as a separate question. That would be good if you want to know about different extensions of a manifold that admits extensions. If you are trying to understand my question then the comments get incorporated into the answer. The goal of SE is to have a single clear question that can have objectively correct answers, and to have good answers to that single question. So a comment that is trying to improve an answer is fine. If I were you I'd ask a new question that utilizes the picture. More questions, more answers.

Comment: I've got it now. **Despite your clear wording** I'd lost track of set openness AND had overlooked the "causal shadows" of the excision. But I was also confused by the overall construction: compact $J^-(p+\hat t,M')\cap J^+(q-\hat t,M')$ implies closedness of both parts and it would have sufficed to show that either was open. I wish there was some notational device to mark sets as open/closed, it would be harder to lose track if there were. Thank you - working through that was very instructive.

Comment: @JulianMoore They are not open. They are simply not closed. A set can be open, closed, both, or neither. These are neither. They contain the exterior boundary (so aren't open) but not the interior boundary (so aren't closed).

Comment: Finally got it! Thx. For others: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set#Open_and_closed_are_not_mutually_exclusive)

Comment: Clarification? If in such proofs it is said that e.g. compact $J^-(p+\hat t,M')\cap J^+(q-\hat t,M')$ implies each part is closed, it does mean that each part is absolutely closed - and not both closed and open - doesn't it? Thus my miswording "it would have sufficed to show either was 'open'" should have been "it would have sufficed to show either was not closed and not (closed and open)"...?

Comment: @JulianMoore It is irrelevant whether it is closed or both closed and open. Compact means compact. There are compacts sets that are both open and closed. You can show it not compact by exhibiting an open cover that doesn't have a finite subcover. Which I now provided. Though I'm bothered by the case where you cut out an open ball. I want to think it isn't GH, but I can't see why it isn't.

Comment: Re excised open ball (corrections expected :) Excising an open ball gives intersecting inextendible curves endpoints, so they cease to be inextendible - doesn't affect the Cauchy surface because it's still met exactly once by every timelike curve that remains inextendible (I had thought it broke things, but it seems it just removes those curves from consideration). But, all Cauchy surfaces in GH are homeomorphic and I don't see that the surface with the excision can be homeomorphic to one without the excisions, so result can't be GH. *If* true, no doubt you can express it better.